# Joint compound or spackle?

Tags: drywall, repair, painting, drywall-mud, spackling-paste

Not sure which of the two I should be using to fix these chips/damages. Which one is better to use on something like this ?[image]

Comment: Until/unless you define "better" this is an opinion-based question and will likely be closed as such. In what way are you looking for one to be "better" than the other? Price? Long lasting? Resistant to moisture that might leak from the AC unit? There are lots of possible "bests".

Comment: There's taping and corner bead to do. That requires Easy Sand (chemically setting) in a bag, not the water soluble premixed stuff in a bucket. That's what you use after you've set the tape and bead because it smooths and sands easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we call spackle mud here where I live. It looks like you have installed a new air conditioner here that will (I’m assuming) have no more moisture issues. I’m a pro, and my advice would be to use a regular premixed mud. You can use a product like DryDex which dries very quickly, but it also dries really hard which makes it less forgiving and harder to sand well. Regular mud has more moisture in it, so it takes longer to dry which makes it a lot easier for DIY. It’s more forgiving, and when dry it’s easier to sand. It does shrink more, but this is not a bad thing.

To prep your area, sand it well (fine grit sanding block). Dust the area with a dry clean cloth.

Make sure the ends of your knives have no chips or divots (sand down the ends of your knives if you do have them).

Understand that you will mud and sand this area multiple times, so there’s no need to get it perfect on the first coat. Apply a thick coat (3mm), and allow to dry fully. If you’re in a rush, you can speed the process along by using a blow dryer on low heat, high output (don’t hold it too close to the mud, it will bubble, 6 inches is good). When dry, sand the area until smooth.Then mud again, hitting the whole area. Dry,sand,dust. This time when you mud, hit the areas that need to be built up. Dry,sand, dust. Use your hand, not your eyes to feel if the mud is sanded smooth, and if the surface is flat.

At this point is is better to have not enough mud (concave) rather than too much (convex). Dust the area with a clean dry cloth.

Apply your first coat of paint. Wait for it to dry, sand it, dust. Any remaining areas that need mud will be more visible this way. You can apply your final patch or 2 at this stage. Dry, sand, dust. Apply a second coat of paint, and then paint the whole wall if possible.

If you believe that your air conditioner will leak moisture again, you can use oil paint on your wall. Oil paint is intense, and I would not recommend it as a DIY. It does withstand moisture well, and can be wiped down repeatedly without lifting any paint.

Tips:

• Sand and dust between patches and after your first coat of paint - if you paint the whole wall sand before you paint and after first coat

•when sanding, use no more pressure than a light touch, repetitive motion is the key

•use one cloth for dusting, but shake it out (outside) between uses

•if you apply mud thickly and you end up with a bunch of tiny holes, sand the area, and then mud the little holes by applying the mud and scraping it gently across holes in all 4 directions, one at a time. Pick up any extra mud with your knife until only a thin coat remains. Dry and sand. Repeat if necessary.

•A new bucket of mud can have a lot of moisture. If it starts to spread on your knife, it’s too wet. You can thicken the mud by putting a dollop on one of your knives, and then use the other knife to push into a small fraction of the mud , drag it across the blade and repeat until your first dollop has moved across your knife. This adds air to the mud, drying it out. I normally do that process 5-6 times. It also smooths out the mud,and removes air bubbles.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing repairs that don't involve taping joints, spackle -- especially non-shrinking spackling compound -- Is Your Friend.